# Filtering jsessionid from url

Tags: java, spring, url, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am implementing session without cookies, but the problem is that if cookies are disabled by default browser send jsessionid in Urls to track session 
http://localhost:8080/basepath/dashboard/admin;jsessionid=8F7E4882D0F2FD804BCC148B0FE3681E

but here jsessionid is getting exposed in url, hence i want to filter jsessionid so that its not printed in url after login.

in WEB-INF/web.xml added below lines

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have created a new urlrewrite.xml which contains below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN" "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
   <rule>
      <note>Remove jsessionid from embedded urls - for urls WITH query parameters</note>
      <from>^/(.*);jsessionid=.*[?](.*)$</from>
      <to type="redirect">/$1?$2</to>
   </rule>
   <rule>
      <note>Remove jsessionid from embedded urls - for urls WITHOUT query parameters</note>
      <from>^/(.*);jsessionid=.*[^?]$</from>
      <to type="redirect">/$1</to>
   </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

But i am still seeing **jsessionid** appended with every request. what is it that i am missing ?

Comment: And then what? How would the client know which sessionid to pass to the server to retrieve the session? So either you should use a cookie (you don't want) or a header, else you are basically starting a session for each request instead of reusing an existing one.

Comment: so if i filter jsessionid from url-  then session will get destroyed ?

Comment: Until it times out, but the client has no way of knowning which session it belongs to.